# Audio recording with Recorder.js and Flask - post data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, flask, audio

**Update**:

I am using recorder.js to record audio from users and I am able to upload the audio file to my Google Cloud Storage bucket. Submitting the form sends the user to the POST route of my Flask app when I test the app locally. However, it hits the GET route when I run the app on Google AppEngine (flex environment).

I think it has to do with the app.js script using XMLHttpRequest and I tried to change app.js to a form post as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit). However, I am new to JavaScript and can't get this to work.

Here is my form:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Recording Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="controls">
            <button id="recordButton">Record</button>
            <button id="pauseButton" disabled>Pause</button>
            <button id="stopButton" disabled>Stop</button>
        </div>
        <ol id="recordingsList"></ol>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/recorder.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the part of the JavaScript I am trying to change to use a regular form post rather than XMLHttpRequest :

```
var upload = document.createElement('a');
upload.href="/record";
upload.innerHTML = "Upload";
upload.addEventListener("click", function(event){
          
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload=function(e) {
        if(this.readyState === 4) {
            console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
        }
    };
    var fd=new FormData();
    fd.append("audio_data",blob, filename);
    xhr.open("POST","/record",true);
    xhr.send(fd);
})
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode (" "))//add a space in between
li.appendChild(upload)//add the upload link to li

//add the li element to the ol
recordingsList.appendChild(li);
}
```

Here is my flask app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, request
    
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/record', methods=['POST'])
def record_post():
    audio_data = request.files['audio_data'].read()
    return 'done with POST'

@app.route('/record', methods=['GET'])
def record():
    return 'done with GET'
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Thank you for your help.

- The source code of recorder.js is here:
  https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs
- A live demo of the recorder.js form is here:
  https://addpipe.com/simple-recorderjs-demo/

Comment: Hey Markus and welcome to SO. Your applications requires a couple of steps to get there. You'll need to capture the recording, encode it to a format you can send to the server and then let the server store the file in your bucket. Then send a response back that everything went great and the upload is done. Do you have any of that? If you do then show us the code relevant to your question, otherwise make an attempt and see where you end up. Beginning a new language can be hard, but we're here to help you out in any way we can, just as long as it's your code we can help you with.

Comment: I have updated the post since I have managed to get the app running locally. My problem is it hits the GET route rather than the POST route when I run it on Google AppEngine (Flex environment).

Comment: It's more likely that you're overwriting your endpoint, resulting in only the `GET` variant existing. Since the `methods` parameter on `@app.route` is plural; try combining the endpoints `methods=['POST', 'GET']`

Comment: Thank you Emiel. I tried that but am getting the same results. Locally it works but not on AppEngine. Here is the revised code:
`code`@app.route('/record', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def record_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        audio_data = request.files['audio_data'].read()
        upload_blob_audio('my-bucket.appspot.com', audio_data, 'folder/subfolder/recorded-audio.wav')
    return 'done with POST'

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue is that the recorded audio file is not uploaded yet when the speech to text function tries to transcribe it. I am going to set up a pub sub topic/ subscription to wait for the upload to be completed now.